# Unwrapping text spans with no class assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove (using jQuery or JavaScript) the spans in text that have no class names assigned to them, but leave the contents intact (preserving spaces and everything) and also leave other spans that have a class name assigned. For instance, I want this

```
<div id="myDiv">I want to <span class="">unwrap</span> but <span class="someClass">keep</span>.</div>
```

To change to this:

```
<div id="myDiv">I want to unwrap but <span class="someClass">keep</span>.</div>
```

I know jQuery unwrap might help, but not sure of how. The spans have no IDs.

Comment: Have you attempted it at all? You seem to know the logic that is required. Try putting together some code asking a question if you're stuck implementing it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('span[class=""]').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
});
```

That should fund all `span` tags with an empty class attributes, then replace it with it's own contents.

**OR** if you *really* want to use `.unwrap()`:

```
$('span[class=""]').each(function() {
    $(this.childNodes).unwrap();
});
```

Comment: As a side note: you could use internal $.fn loop in this case: `$('span[class=""]').replaceWith(function(){ return this.childNodes});`. And using `$.fn.unwrap()`: `$('span[class=""]').contents().unwrap();`